# Can anyone give me an example about unit testing in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I am new in iOS development and want to learn unit testing. I want to add two numbers using text fields and show the result in a label when clicking on the action. Can anyone suggest me how to make a unit test for this?

Comment: The calculation is UnitTested, the action + presentation is UITest

Comment: Since you are talking about a thing that is composed from multiple units and cannot really be mocked (UIKit), it's impossible to *unit* test it. You need an integration/e2e test.

Answer (score 2):

This is a short example, but you should always try multple different variations as if it would be text instead of numbers and negative numbers, numbers that is higher than int etc...

```
class AddingViewController: UIViewController {

    var sum = 0

    let textField1 = UITextField()
    let textField2 = UITextField()
    let button = UIButton()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addNumbers), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func addNumbers() {
        guard let number1 = Int(textField1.text!), let number2 = Int(textField2.text!) else {
            return
        }
        sum = number1 + number2
    }
}

class TestAddingViewController {

    let vc = AddingViewController()

    func testAddNumbers() {
        let number1 = 1
        let number2 = 2
        let sum = number1 + number2
        vc.textField1.text = "\(number1)"
        vc.textField2.text = "\(number2)"
        vc.button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
        XCTAssertEqual(sum, vc.sum)
    }
}
```

If viewController is from storyboard you call it as you normally call storyboard viewControllers

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
```

And the textfields + button will be `@outlets` and the button action will be an `@IBAction` and not `@objc func`

Comment: What would this look like when the textfields are loaded from the storyboard?

Comment: Edited for storyboard approach also

Answer (score -1):

Here is my view controller class:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   // MARK: ▼▼▼ IBOutlets ▼▼▼
   @IBOutlet weak var lblAnswer: UILabel!

   // MARK: ▼▼▼ Lifecycle methods ▼▼▼
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      lblAnswer.text = "\(calculateSum(num1: 5, num2: 10))"
   }

   // MARK: ▼▼▼ Methods ▼▼▼
   func calculateSum(num1: Int, num2: Int) -> Int {
      return (num1 + num2)
   }
}
```

And for the unit test class I have:

```
import XCTest
@testable import Test

class TestTests: XCTestCase {

// MARK: ▼▼▼ Variables ▼▼▼
var num1: Int?
var num2: Int?
var testClass: ViewController?

// This is used to initialise your code:
override func setUp() {
    testClass = ViewController()
    num1 = 10
    num2 = 10
}

// This runs when test is complete:
override func tearDown() {
    testClass = nil
    num1 = nil
    num2 = nil
}

// Should begin with test so that it is recognised:
func testSumFunction() {
    let sum = testClass!.calculateSum(num1: num1!, num2: num2!)
    // The sum should be 20 for this to pass.
    XCTAssertTrue(sum == 20)
}
}
```

If the logic of the function is changed and answer is not equal to 20 then this test will fail.